# Alloytools crashed and does not start anymore

Tags: alloy

I was changing the font of the Alloy-Tool editor and it crashed. Now I'm unable to launch it, returning this every time I try: [screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERKkg.png)

I've also tried to download different versions of alloy but each of them return the same error. Is there any way to modify some configuration file that they use at the startup?

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Can you provide more details such as - the font you changed to, any logs (if applicable), any alloy configuration files (if applicable)?

Comment: Maybe I selected a font that is not supported by the editor while I was switching through them. I cannot find neither a log file 
nor a config since the tool is distribuited as a .jar file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:
modify this .xml file under your home directory

```
/.java/.userPrefs/edu/mit/csail/sdg/alloy4/pref.xml
```

with another font name at the entry

```
<entry key="FontName" value="FontNameHere"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you run it from the command line? If this error happens it should show an exception trace. Please report this trace on https://github.com/AlloyTools/org.alloytools.alloy/issues